# Error: Can't resolve when try use alias (webpack/typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, tsconfig, react-tsx

Trying to shorten the path when importing.

The IDE does not show the error, but the following error appears during compilation:
``
ERROR in ./src/app/providers/router/ui/AppRouter.tsx 6:0-70
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/shared/config/routeConfig/routeConfig' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\projects\cosmetic\src\app\providers\router\ui'

``

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "include": [
      "src"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    }
  },
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js
export default () => {

const paths: BuildPath = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
    build: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    html: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
    src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
}
const mode = 'development';
const isDev = mode === 'development';
const config: webpack.Configuration = buildWebpackConfig({
    mode: "development",
    paths,
    isDev
})
    return config
}
```

```
// resolvers config for webpack
export function buildResolvers(options: BuildOptions): ResolveOptions {
    return {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        preferAbsolute: true,
        modules: [options.paths.src, 'node-modules'],
        mainFiles: ['index'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        }
    }
}
```

Added "baseUrl": "." / "src"